# Mapping and slicing column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a visit_start_time column which is in this format: "31/08/2019 20:36"

I want to create a `Visit_date` column which includes just the date of the visit, for example `31/08/2019`.

I tried to use map function and split just the string.

```
active_visits_StpNshp.rename(columns={'visit_start_time':'visit_date'},inplace=True)
  
active_visits_StpNshp['visit_date'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

But it just doesn't work - the column stays with the same values.

Comment: check df.info() if its datetime , convert into string by apply astype(str). then apply your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys i solved this using this code:

```
active_visits_StpNshp['visit_date'] = active_visits_StpNshp['visit_date'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

the map method return the Series object i just had to reasign it.

Answer (score 0):

Since we cannot apply split method directly to list, convert the datetime into string and then apply split.
map will convert into series.

```
active_visits_StpNshp['visit_date'] = active_visits_StpNshp['visit_date'].astype(str)
df = active_visits_StpNshp['visit_date'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

This will give you a new series 'df' with proper date format.

if you want this as a dataframe to_frame is the method.

```
df2 = (df.to_frame())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
Visit_date = visit_start_time.split(" ")[0]
```

Comment: could you write an example how to implement this, you wrote this as common string